scikit-learn can not fit the model when the target variable is object type
I tried to create a logistic regression model using scikit-learn library.
When I tried to fit the model with object type as target variable (y), it didn't work and returned error.
Then I switched the target variable into integer and it works. Is it impossible to create model with object type as target variable ?
I expect scikit-learn logistic regression also works with object data type as target variable.
Because in my case I need create prediction in an object / categorical type.
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(df[['Loan_Amount_Requested','Debt_To_Income']],df['Interest_Rate_New'])


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
last)  in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(df[['Loan_Amount_Requested','Debt_To_Income']],df['Interest_Rate_New'])
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in
check_classification_targets(y)
216         "multilabel-sequences",
217     ]:
--> 218         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
219
220
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'

error message

don't post your errors as images, see How to Ask, furthermore what type of object are your... for lack of a better word "objects"

no problem, i'm going to be annoying a little longer though, what object type are your objects? i'd assume strings? some sample data would be nice tbh

@KenzoStaelens yes it's strings

i would like to try and ask again for some sample data of your dataframe (a few rows is probably enough). a quick test with the following dataframe df = pd.DataFrame({"Loan_Amount_Requested":[1,2,3],"Debt_To_Income":[0.1,0.2,0.3],"Interest_Rate_New":["10%","20%","30%"]}) doesn't seem to cause any issues, is it possible some non-string data ended up in Interest_Rate_New?

"is it possible some non-string data ended up in Interest_Rate_New?" is also my guess. For that, what's the output of df['Interest_Rate_New'].value_counts(dropna=False)?
